# Get all pages of a embedded power bi report

Tags: angular, report, powerbi-embedded

I'm developing a embedded power bi application in angular 4.
This application groups several reports (stored on Azure) and i would like to retrieve all pages of each report without having to load it into a container. The power bi api apparently doesn't allow this; is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do so using the current REST APIs Power BI has.
You would probably need to use `preload` (or Warm-starting) to load the metadata of the report without having to render it to screen.

See here for more info:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Phased-Embedding-API

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but possible useful for others like me looking for some code snippets
The following gets all report pages and creates buttons to embed them on a different page.

Note that this is from ASP.NET CORE MVC and I can render my secure embed information from the supplied model.

Hope this helps...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var preloadElement = powerbi.preload({
    type: "report",
    baseUrl: "https://embedded.powerbi.com/reportEmbed",
  });

  $(preloadElement).on("preloaded", function () {
    setupEnhancedReportLinks(
      "#enhanced-report-container",
      @Json.Serialize(Model.EnhancedReports)
    );
  });
});

function setupEnhancedReportLinks(containerName, reportsModel) {
  $.each(reportsModel, function () {
    const config = {
      type: "report",
      id: this.id,
      embedUrl: this.embedUrl,
      accessToken: this.embedToken.token,
      tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
      permissions: models.Permissions.All,
      viewMode: models.ViewMode.View,
      settings: {
        filterPaneEnabled: false,
        navContentPaneEnabled: false,
      },
    };

    let elements = [];
    elements.push(
      $("<h4> ")
        .attr({ id: `title-for-${config.id}` })
        .text(this.displayName)
    );
    elements.push($("<div>").attr({ id: `buttons-for-${config.id}` }));

    // Note this element is hidden; loading a report still requires a page element to contain it, so we hide it on creation
    elements.push(
      $("<div>")
        .attr({ id: `report-for-${config.id}` })
        .hide()
    );

    // add all report information into the main dom element
    $(containerName).append(
      $("<div>")
        .attr({ id: `container-for-${config.id}`, class: "well col-lg-12" })
        .append(elements)
    );

    // Load the report
    // fetch, then iterate the pages to create the buttons which are added to the report's button container
    var report = powerbi.load($(`#report-for-${config.id}`)[0], config);
    report.on("loaded", function () {
      report.getPages().then(function (pages) {
        $.each(pages, function () {
          console.log("is this a page", this, config);
          $(`#buttons-for-${config.id}`).append(
            $("<a>")
              .text(this.displayName)
              .attr({
                href: `/EmbeddedReport/EmbedReport?reportId=${config.id}&reportSection=${this.name}`,
                class: "enh-button",
              })
          );
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```